# Reading a TXT File with VBA suddenly doesn't work anymore

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am in the process of converting some old Macros from Word 2003 to Word 2013. I thought I would only have to build a fancy Ribbon Bar and be done with it, but apparently not.

The following code is supposed to read the whole content of a TXT File and put it into the Clipboard.
This is how I create the object and make the call to my Function:

```
Dim MyData As DataObject
Set MyData = New DataObject
MyData.SetText LoadTextFile("C:\TESTDOCS\readthisfile.txt")
MyData.PutInClipboard
```

And this is the actual Function:

```
 Public Function LoadTextFile(sFile As String) As String
    Dim iFile As Integer
    On Local Error Resume Next

    iFile = FreeFile

    Open sFile For Input As #iFile

    LoadTextFile = Input$(LOF(iFile), iFile)
    Close #iFile


 End Function
```

Afterwards I'm getting the following error:

```
Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)':
DataObject:SetText Invalid Argument.
```

And as I said: This code works just fine in Word 2003 with the same file.

Comment: Did you try Debugging?

Comment: Yeah, it runs through LoadTextFile just fine and then I get the error when it tries to pass the string to MyData.SetText

Comment: So using `MyData.SetText "Hello World"` works?

Comment: Which suggests the `LoadTextFile` is the problem. I see you use `On Error Resume Next`, which is not the sharpest knife in the drawer when it comes to Error handling. Try commenting it out and debug again.

Comment: +1 for @PaulFrancis, this would help to know this! And I'm not sure but I think DataObject class is in default references, if not try to add the respective reference. take a look here, there might be some useful info : http://winwiki.org/vba-run-time-error-80070057/

Comment: Now I'm getting RUntime error 62: Input past end of file. I tried putting the LOF line inside a do while loop where I check EOF but it has the same result

Comment: Please use @ tags to notify the corresponding people (when more than one user is involved in comments), so we will get notified immediately. Or your comment gets unnoticed. However, try the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your error, I would suggest that you read the text file one line at a time, looping through till the EOF (End Of File). This will give you a bit more flexibility. Here is how you need to modify your `LoadTextFile` method to get it right,

```
Public Function LoadTextFile(sFile As String) As String
On Error GoTo errHandler
    Dim iFile As Integer, strIn As String, tmpStr As String

    Open sFile For Input As #iFile

    Do While Not EOF(iFile)
        Line Input #iFile, tmpStr
        strIn = strIn & tmpStr
    Loop

    LoadTextFile = strIn
exitHandler:
    Close #iFile
    Exit Function
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Error (" & Err.Number & ") - " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Exiting LoadTextFile Method.", vbInformation
    Resume exitHandler
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but this gets me an endless Loop. It reads the file for a bit and then displays Error 0, Error 20, Error 0....